# Not getting 31 bytes of BLE device Name in Android

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

BLE  is not showing full 31 bytes of advertisement name(device name)
in Android while fetching `getname()` from BLE device. 
It showing only 26 bytes of data. Please help me, I am new to this BLE Development.

Comment: Are you talking about `BluetoothAdapter.getName`? _"Valid Bluetooth names are a maximum of 248 bytes using UTF-8 encoding, although many remote devices can only display the first 40 characters, and some may be limited to just 20."_

Comment: yes sir. How to get atleast 32 bytes from this BLE device

Comment: Are you able to verify that the BLE device you are using is working properly by using other apps are able to get all 31 bytes?